# How to pass enum from class to form?

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

I have created an **enum** called *'direction'* in a class for easy "snake" game. But I don't know how to pass values from this class to the main form...

**What I tried?**

**1)** I tried to create the same enum in class and in form, but there was a conversion problem (Argument1: Cannot convert from *'Project.Form1.direction'* to *'Class.direction'*

**2)** I tried it with parameters passing, but I failed.

Then I tried some stupid things, which I can't mention here.

I am attaching also a declaration, maybe it'll help you.

```
//Declaration in the main form is the same as the declaration in the class. 

public enum direction { stop, up, down, left, right };

//Each part of enum is for the direction of the snake.
```

Comment: You could create `enum` in class and create property for that `enum` in main form like `public direction directions{get;}`

Answer (score 2):

You only need to define the enum once.  If you declare your enum in a public class called snake, like this:

```
    public class Snake
    {
        public enum direction { stop, up, down, left, right };

        //rest of class
    }
```

You can use the enum outside the Snake class by using the type `Snake.direction`

**EDIT**

Or you can just declare your enum outside of any class.

```
    public class Snake
    {
        //class
    }

    public enum direction { stop, up, down, left, right };
```

Then you can just use `direction` to access the enum

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is best to define an [enum directly within a namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) so that all classes in the namespace can access it with equal convenience. However, an enum can also be nested within a class or struct. Here simple example of the first approach, HTH

> Direction.cs defines `enum Direction`

```
namespace Snake.Game.Enums
{
    public enum Direction
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right
    };
}
```

> File `SnakeGame.cs` defines the class which has property of type `Direction`

```
using Snake.Game.Enums;

namespace Snake.Game.Classes
{
    public class SnakeGame
    {
        public Direction Direction { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> `SnakeGameForm.cs` defines the form and in constructor it becomes instance of type `SnakeGame` and so the form knows every time how the `Direction` is.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Snake.Game.Classes;

namespace Snake.Game.Forms
{
    public partial class SnakeGameForm : Form
    {
        private readonly SnakeGame _game;

        public SnakeGameForm(SnakeGame game)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _game = game;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Direction of snake is '{ _game.Direction}'.");
        }
    }
}
```